# How do I set up a Google Cloud Function with Authentication?

Tags: rest, google-cloud-functions

Disclaimer: I'm completely new to Google Cloud Functions and serverless functions in general.

I've set up a basic Google Cloud Function, set it to HTTPS trigger and Require Authentication, and given the service account and my account the cloud function invoker role.

However, whenever I use Postman to sent an HTTP request to the function using my oauth2 token, I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I've also followed the steps here: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating

to create and download the service account key and make an HTTP request using cURL and get the same error.

How do I need to set this up so that authorized users can send HTTP requests to this function?

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$gcloud auth login (to log in with my account with cloud invoker permission)
$curl https://my-trigger-url \ -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
```

Comment: Can you share your code or your CURL? It's not so difficult, but you have to know/view how to do! Tips: use an identity token and not an access token, with the correct audience!

Comment: Hi Guillaume,  
  
Here's what I'm doing  
  
`$gcloud auth login`  
(to log in with my account with cloud invoker permission)  
  
`$curl https://my-trigger-url \ -H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"` 
  
That returns: 403 Forbidden, "Your client does not have permission to get URL"

Comment: Can you put the `-H ...` BEFORE the URL?

Comment: Funnily enough, yes I got a successful response when I did that, Thank you!

So when making calls to the Cloud Function from apps other than cURL, I need to include that ID token in the header?

Comment: If I know the trick, it's because I made the mistake!!! And yes, you must include the authorization header in all the requests. It's an identity token for Cloud Run, Cloud Functions and App Engine; but when you call a Google Cloud API, you must add an access token.

Answer (score 1):

Guillaume found the solution:

My cURL syntax to trigger the Cloud Function needed the `-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"` before the URL instead of after, which is the opposite of Google's own documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this does not warrant as answer. This can be put in as comment or as edit to question